# jquery mobile with dangero.us swiper dynamic content problems

Tags: jquery, mobile, dynamic, swiper.js

I am working on a jquery mobile web app. I've tried integrating dangero.us swiper.
I fill my swiper-container with dynamic html. I've tried using the reinit()-function after inserting html, like described in other tasks, but nothing happend.

this is my html:

```
  <div data-role="page" id="slider">
     .....
     <div class="swiper-container">

        <div class="swiper-wrapper">  <!-- wrapper -->


             <div id="slidecontent"></div>  <!-- dyn. html here -->


        </div>  <!-- wrapper -->

 </div>
```

this is my code for filling dynamic content, initialise the swiper-instance an call reinit()-function

```
$('#slider').on('pageinit', function(event) {

  $('#slidecontent').load('slider_input.html').trigger("create");

  // div containers loading

});


   $(document).on('pageshow', '#slider', function(){ 

 var myapp2goSwiper = $('.swiper-container').swiper({
     pagination: '.pagination',
     paginationClickable: true,
     slidesPerView: 1,
     loop: true,
      onSlideClick : function(swiper) {
      //Do something when you touch the slide

      var i = myapp2goSwiper.clickedSlideIndex;

      var a = myapp2goSwiper.activeSlide();

      console.log(i);

      console.log(a);

      }


 }); 

 //myapp2goSwiper.reInit();
 reinitSwiper(myapp2goSwiper);

});


function reinitSwiper(swiper) {
setTimeout(function () {
    swiper.reInit();
}, 500);

};
```

Nothing is shown in my browser. What can i do to refresh or reinit my html-content that the swiper-instance is working correctly? A live-demo is at http://www.m.myapp2go.de/myapp2go-slide.html

**I solved my problem.** Appending my html-content to `<div id="slidecontent"></div>` was wrong. I have to append the html-content to  `<div class="swiper-wrapper">` directly.

Now it's working, but:

- pagination is not shown anymore
- onSlideClick doesn't fire anymore

Any suggestions?

Comment: I noticed that your app now is working, can you please tell what you did? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to call the createpagination method in the swiper's js file to update the pagination in the reinit function as follows and it worked.

Go to line 741 in the minified js file of version 2.1. There will be a reinit method as written below. This method needs to be called to reinitialize the swiper in case it is generated dynamically.I have called the createPagination() method in reinit so as to update the pagination as follows.The reinit method by default calls only the init method so the pagination doesn't get updated.

```
a.reInit = function(b) {
   a.init(!0, b);
   a.createPagination();
};
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Can you please specify better what you did? It is an issue I'm also facing and I can get out of it! Please post some code or a better description.. thank you!

Comment: @SimonaAdriani : edited my comment. Check if it helps!! Revert back in case u need more clarification o mail me through my id in the profile.